# Codename One Preferences/Storage permissions

Tags: codenameone

I have developed and published an app in Google Play Store, which only send simple `String` request to REST API and store the results in the `Preferences`. The same app is also submitted to Windows Store for publication, however it was rejected due to the following reason:

> The app declares use of the sensitive capability [musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary] without appearing to access the declared capability. Please removed the sensitive capability declaration and re-submit the app.

Upon inspection to Google Play Store submission, I noticed the same permissions are requested:

> This app has access to:
>
> 1. Photos/Media/Files
>
>    - read the contents of your USB storage
>    - modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
> 2. Storage
>
>    - read the contents of your USB storage
>    - modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
> 3. Other
>
>    - receive data from Internet
>    - view network connections
>    - full network access
>    - prevent device from sleeping

So my question is, do `Preferences` really need these permissions, or can I set some kind of build hints to remove these permission requests, especially for UWP build? I have also tried to set `android.blockExternalStoragePermission` build hint, but the permissions are still requested in Android build. I have yet to try iOS build since currently I don't have Apple Developer account.

Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit #1 (23/10/2018):**

Upon further inspection, I found that I have mistakenly uploaded the version that didn't declare `android.blockExternalStoragePermission` to Google Play Store, so all good on Android version.

Currently I'm not using any of cn1libs, and here's the list of all classes imported in my application:

`java.util.HashMap`

`java.util.Map`

`java.util.Random`

`com.codename1.components.InfiniteProgress`

`com.codename1.components.ToastBar`

`com.codename1.components.ToastBar.Status`

`com.codename1.io.CharArrayReader`

`com.codename1.io.JSONParser`

`com.codename1.io.Log`

`com.codename1.io.NetworkManager`

`com.codename1.io.Preferences`

`com.codename1.io.rest.Response`

`com.codename1.io.rest.Rest`

`com.codename1.l10n.L10NManager`

`com.codename1.ui.Button`

`com.codename1.ui.Component`

`com.codename1.ui.Container`

`com.codename1.ui.Dialog`

`com.codename1.ui.FontImage`

`com.codename1.ui.Form`

`com.codename1.ui.Label`

`com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent`

`com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener`

`com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout`

`com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout`

`com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout`

`com.codename1.ui.plaf.Border`

`com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style`

`com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager`

`com.codename1.ui.util.Resources`

So my original question remain, how do I set the build hints to prevent the same external storage read/write permission in Windows and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

See the section titled "Android Permissions" [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html), for a list of some API's that might trigger extra permissions. I suggest extracting the manifest from the XML and inspecting it. It should include two permissions based on your description you should have two permissions there:

- `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` - which you should have been disabled when you applied `android.blockExternalStoragePermission`
- `android.permission.INTERNET` - this one you actually need

I'm assuming you have a permission for media access and here it becomes a question of where it came from?

Did you use a cn1lib that might include a feature that triggers this?

Do you have a feature in the app that isn't active yet?

Once you have the specific name or results of this investigation comment here and I'll revise the answer with more details.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but please see my edit for the question. Thank you very much, @ShaiAlmog.

Comment: iOS doesn't need that permission and "just works". I don't see any suspicious class in that list I'll have to check about the UWP port